# Changing font-lock color in SMerge mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

In Emacs 23.1 I'm opening up a file with conflict markers from a svn merge and consequently it opens it up in SMerge mode.  The conflicted text is highlighted in bright yellow.  From what I could find this is whatever the font-lock color is set to, correct?

I'd like to change the highlight color in SMerge mode.  What would I need to add to my .emacs file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need to mess with `list-faces-display` or manual file editing.  Put the point on the color you hate, type `M-x customize-face`, press `ENT` (the default is correct), and follow the on-screen instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a custom color theme [0], that I load in my .emacs.  When I come across something that's ugly, I use `M-x list-faces-display` to find the offending faces.  Then you just update your color theme accordingly.

(An example of my color theme is here [1])

0 - http://github.com/mattharrison/emacs-tango-theme

1 - http://panela.blog-city.com/python_and_emacs_2_color_themes.htm

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction.  I used M-x list-faces-display and then customized it there.  And since I set a custom-file it saves this off so I'll have it for next time.  I love emacs :)